# Platform that allows configurable entities, relationships, workflows, security/visibility (with teams & hierarchy), portal

Tags: web-apps

What free/open packages are available that are like a platform that allows administrators to configure (rather than code) entities, relationships between them (XRM not just CRM), rule-based workflows and actions, security and visibility (with teams and hierarchies), portals for external users, and some marketing automation.

Perhaps it would look like a mash-up of SuiteCRM, Drupal, and Mautic.  (By themselves, SuiteCRM isn't functional enough, Drupal quickly requires modules that lag behind the Drupal release and/or PHP coding, and Mautic is too siloed to be the full solution.)  Perhaps it would look like MS Dynamics CRM or Salesforce.com or NetSuite or a Zoho suite.  But free and open.  ERPAL for Drupal looks really promising but I've tried the demo and it's just not user friendly.  Also, [ERPAL is far from ready](https://www.drupal.org/node/2606002#actions) for the current Drupal release (v8), and I'm not certain if a v7 site would ever be upgradeable.

I am not interested in Teaseware or software that is only free for limited functionality or for a limited number of users or for a limited amount of entities or data or some combination thereof.

It should be a web app for both the users and the administrators/configurators/developers.  It should be able to be hosted on any of the popular hosting sites with a popular DB backend like MySQL.

I realize there may not be anything available that is free/open.  But perhaps there is something out there that I haven't yet run across.

Comment: Only looking at your first paragraph, I'd say "go for Drupal". But your next parg indicates that's not what you want to consider. How much experience/background do you have about Drupal? Do you have OTHER reasons why (you think) Drupal does not fit? If so, please add them also to your question. Also, are you interested in an answer that might have you reconsider Drupal (only) anyway? PS: what is XRM?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens, I like Drupal, but a lot of its modules lag behind the release.  For example, neither the "Prepopulate" module nor the "Entityreference prepopulate" modules are available for Drupal 8.  And, they appear to be the only way to prepopulate a child entity with a reference to the parent entity from which you are starting.  (E.g. if you're viewing "Company A" and you want to quickly create a new contact for it without reselecting "Company A".)   XRM is "X" Relationship Management, which probably includes customers, but is certainly not limited to customers.